# Dreamweaver CC: CSS file causes white screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver CC (please refrain from denigrating the use of this program) and have been fooling around with my .css file all day.  When I opened the `bootstrap.css` file, I selected "make writeable" (I realize that this is something you should avoid) and then almost instantly my view went blank.

When I remove the link to my custom .css file, the text appears, but once I link the HTML to the .css file, the view goes blank.  This file seems to have the same effect on other HTML pages making me believe the .css file is the problem.

Here is my code, please help me find whats going on:

```
@charset "utf-8";
h1, h3, h2, p {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
#main {
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.navbar, .navbar-default {
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
footer {
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #383838;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-fill {
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
#floating {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #000000;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: visible;
    float: none;
    top: 0pt;
    position: absolute;
    left: 62px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 99px;
}

body{
    text-align: center;
}

.test-center {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Stable */
.instructions {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 92;
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: medium solid rgba(7,255,35,1.00);
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: none;
}

.instruction-text {
    color: rgba(7,255,35,1.00);
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    font-family: immi-five-o-five;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.instruction-text-header {
    color: rgba(7,255,35,1.00);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: immi-five-o-five;
    font-size: 50px;
}


/* Mutable */

.instructions-min {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-top: medium solid rgba(7,255,35,1.00);
    border-bottom: hidden;
    border-left: hidden;
    border-right: hidden;
}

.smallfont {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.test-center {
    display: inline-block;
}

.instruction-loc-big {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.instruction-loc-mini {
    top: 92%;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="testing.js"></script>
    <script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/caesar-dressing:n4:default;lobster-two:n4:default;chicle:n4:default;henny-penny:n4:default;immi-five-o-five:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body class="center">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid instructions instruction-loc-big">
        <h1 class="instruction-text-header">How It Works</h1>
        <div class="minimizable">
          <h3 class="instruction-text">1. Sign Up/Sign In </h3>
          <h3 class="instruction-text">2. Click a flyer </h3>
          <h3 class="instruction-text">3. Get your ticket </h3>
          <h3 class="instruction-text">4. Forward your ticket order confirmation</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your "view"? Is that the preview area or whatever it is in Dreamweaver or the site actually viewed in a browser?

Comment: Sounds to me like a dreamweaver specific problem!

Comment: Either.  It is quite frustrating.  I've attached my html file

Comment: Do you want the `display: none;` in your `.instructions`?

Comment: no, I did not!  Must've been added through clicking something accidentally.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CSS file at line 69 you have set `.instructions` with `display:none`.

So all your content is hidden.